# JSF Ajax addClientBehavior gives null.pointer.exception

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, custom-component

I'm trying to add programatically an Ajax client behavior to a custom component but when I do I get a null.pointer.exception (as an Alert in the browser no error in the logs), if I add the behavior in the .xhtml it works fine but I really need to add them programatically (actually the component is going to be rendered dinamically from a top component (dashboard -> N columns -> N widgets per column all from a Database)

I have tested this creating a simple DataList component

Here is the relevant code...

DataListRenderer

```
@Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException{
        DataList datalist = (DataList)component;
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

        .. bunch of rendering options....

        // If sortable then we add the sortable script.
        // This basically ends up generating a call to jsf.ajax.request(source,event,params);
        if (sortable != null && sortable.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            ScriptUtils.startScript(writer, clientId);
            writer.write("$(function() {");

            writer.write("$(EasyFaces.escapeId('" + clientId + "')).sortable({");
            writer.write("update: function (event, ui) { ");

            writer.write(new AjaxRequest().addEvent(StringUtils.addSingleQuotes("update"))
                                .addExecute(StringUtils.addSingleQuotes(datalist.getClientId()))
                      .addSource(StringUtils.addSingleQuotes(datalist.getClientId()))
                      .addOther("sourceId", "ui.item.attr('id')")
                      .addOther("dataValue", "ui.item.attr('data-value')")
                      .addOther("dropedPosition", "ui.item.index()")
                      .getAjaxCall());

            writer.write(" } ");
            encodeClientBehaviors(context, datalist);
            writer.write("});");
            writer.write("});");
            ScriptUtils.endScript(writer);

        }

         // This is where I add the behavior
        AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = (AjaxBehavior) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
        ajaxBehavior.setRender(Arrays.asList("@form"));
        ajaxBehavior.setExecute(Arrays.asList("@form"));
        MethodExpression listener = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
                .getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(),"#{dataListManager.updateModel}", null,
                        new Class[] { AjaxBehaviorEvent.class });
        ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(listener));
        datalist.addClientBehavior(datalist.getDefaultEventName(), ajaxBehavior);

    }

    ... rest of the code
```

Now the .xhtml is as follows:

```
...

    h:form>
      <et:dataList id="dl" value="#{easyfacesBean.data}" itemValue="foo" var="xx" sortable="true">
        <h:outputText id="txt" value="#{xx}" />
      </et:dataList>
    </h:form>
...
```

This renders the code Ok, the list actually can be ordered but when re-ordered it gives me the null.pointer.exception error

This is what comes back from the server:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><error><error-name>class java.lang.NullPointerException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[]]></error-message></error></partial-response>
```

Now, If I comment this line

```
datalist.addClientBehavior(datalist.getDefaultEventName(), ajaxBehavior);
```

And simply add the  tag like so:

```
<h:form>
      <et:dataList id="dl" value="#{easyfacesBean.data}" itemValue="foo" var="xx" sortable="true">
      <f:ajax />
        <h:outputText id="txt" value="#{xx}" />
      </et:dataList>
    </h:form>
```

Everything works fine.. any ideas? I would settle for a way to actually know where the null.point.exception is ..

BTW if I don't comment the line that actually add's the behavior and add the < f:ajax > tag the error changes to java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><error><error-name>class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[Index: 1, Size: 1]]></error-message>
```

Regards!